# Change of mailing address

Tags: visas, uk, application-status

I applied for the UK business visa on September 19. I had to shift to a new place today, which is not mentioned in my visa application. Should I inform them about the change of address?

Comment: Should I do so by filling that email form available on the UKVI website?

Comment: Presumably you should. How else would you do it?

Comment: I'm not sure. Visa applications from Pakistan are processed in the UAE, so guess there is no other way.

Comment: Start by telling the VFS you submitted to.  They will know what to do next.

Comment: They don't have any phone number/email of their own and won't allow entry without an appointment.

Comment: Which VFS is it?

Comment: It's Islamabad.

Comment: Also, won't they get suspicious if I tell them about the change of address at this stage (3rd week)?

Comment: I contacted them through their e-mail form. They said it won't be an issue unless I asked for passport delivery via courier. I did however mention that during my interview and the ECO said that's fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I inform them about the change of address?

Yes.